# How to apply r2_score per group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
dt = {
    "Item Id" : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    "Projected Sales" : [10, 20, 30, 40, 49, 4, 2, 3, 4, 10, 22],
    "Actual Sales": [4, 5, 3, 10, 4, 42, 23, 1, 19, 24, 22]
}

sample_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dt)
```

Output:

```
    Item Id  Projected Sales  Actual Sales
0         1               10             4
1         1               20             5
2         1               30             3
3         2               40            10
4         2               49             4
5         3                4            42
6         4                2            23
7         5                3             1
8         5                4            19
9         5               10            24
10        5               22            22
```

I am trying to generate a new DataFrame with a schema like:

```
Item Id  R2_Score
x        y
...
```

Where the R2 score is the R2 value for that item_id. I've written this following code:

```
def r2_per_group(data, truth, predicted):
    score = r2_score(data[truth], data[predicted])

    print(score)

    return r2_score(data[truth], data[predicted])

result = sample_df.groupby('Item Id').apply(r2_per_group, 'Actual Sales', 'Projected Sales')
```

While this works fine for this small dataframe. However, I need to run this for a much larger dataframe ~5000000 rows with over 2000 groups and I'm seeing inconsistent results where the r2_value printed out is not the r2_value observed in the resulting dataframe for certain Item IDs.

I am pretty lost on how this could happen.

Comment: Pasting your code I get an error. Are you missing an argument for the data in the apply piece of the group-by?

Answer (score 0):

This actually works exactly as intended. For some reason I trusted the displayed R2_Score for certain cells when doing

```
result_df.head
```

but if you actually locate the cell, it displays the correct answer. Weird.